# Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables with below query.

```
(SELECT CustomerName, OrderDate,
LAG(OrderDate,1) OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as Previous_Order_Date
FROM Table1) as t1
INNER JOIN  (SELECT CustomerName, MAX(OrderDate) as Latest_Order_date
             FROM Table1
             GROUP BY CustomerName) as t2
ON t1.CustomerName = t2.CustomerName AND t1.OrderDate = t2.Latest_Order_date
```

But I get below error:

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerName, MAX(OrderDate) as Latest_Order_date ' at line 3

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e79cciNYBBtgaaGKcRauV4/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an outer select clause:

```
SELECT
    t1.CustomerName,
    t1.Previous_Order_Date,
    t2.Latest_Order_date
FROM
(
    SELECT CustomerName, OrderDate,
        LAG(OrderDate,1) OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) AS Previous_Order_Date
    FROM Table1
) AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustomerName, MAX(OrderDate) AS Latest_Order_date
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY CustomerName
) AS t2
    ON t1.CustomerName = t2.CustomerName AND t1.OrderDate = t2.Latest_Order_date;
```

But actually you *might* be able to simplify your query to not even use any joins:

```
SELECT
    t.CustomerName,
    t.Previous_Order_Date,
    t.Latest_Order_date
FROM
(
    SELECT CustomerName, OrderDate,
        LAG(OrderDate,1) OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) AS Previous_Order_Date,
        MAX(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName) AS Latest_Order_date
    FROM Table1
) t
WHERE
    t.Previous_Order_Date = t.Latest_Order_date;
```

This would be correct if each row which passed in your join matched to one and only record.

Note that your current syntax would actually be valid on MySQL if what came between the subqueries were `UNION` instead of join.  That is, the following is valid syntax:

```
(SELECT CustomerName, OrderDate FROM Table1)
UNION
(SELECT CustomerName, OrderDate FROM Table1)
```

Comment: My aim is to get latest_order_date and previous_order_date (the one just before the latest order date) for each customer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a part such as

```
SELECT t1.CustomerName, t1.Previous_Order_Date, t2.Latest_Order_date
  FROM
```

for the above part of the query as :

```
SELECT t1.CustomerName, t1.Previous_Order_Date, t2.Latest_Order_date
  FROM (SELECT CustomerName,
               OrderDate,
               LAG(OrderDate, 1) OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as Previous_Order_Date
          FROM Table1) as t1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomerName, MAX(OrderDate) as Latest_Order_date
               FROM Table1
              GROUP BY CustomerName) as t2
    ON t1.CustomerName = t2.CustomerName
   AND t1.OrderDate = t2.Latest_Order_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a main select statement.

Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CustomerName, OrderDate,
LAG(OrderDate,1) OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) as Previous_Order_Date
FROM Table1) as t1
INNER JOIN  (SELECT CustomerName, MAX(OrderDate) as Latest_Order_date
             FROM Table1
             GROUP BY CustomerName) as t2
ON t1.CustomerName = t2.CustomerName AND t1.OrderDate = t2.Latest_Order_date
```

MySQL select needs a query in the format:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN (SELECT id, value FROM table3) as t3
  on t3.id = t2.id
WHERE t3.value IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Outer `SELECT *` is usually bad, and an anti-pattern.